# why this code giving different output than expected?

Tags: c++, output

While I'm solving some questions improving my skills using similar code, I get the output 'a@' for the code below
I inputted 10 'a''s

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[11];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cin >> a;
    string s(a);
    cout << s;
    cout << a[3];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the input.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cin >> a;` doesn't do what you think it does. Also, if you are complaining about discrepancy between expected behavior and actual one, your question **must** contain input, expected output, actual output and your reasoning why expected output is expected.

Comment: `std::string` is going to expect `a` to be null-terminated, which it is not. Ensure `a[10]` is equal to `'\0'`

Comment: I'm sorry I input 10 a's

Comment: what did you expect as output?

Comment: @ChakerTriangle, if you want to assign an `"a"` to each element of array you rather need to write it like: `cin >> a[i];` and set '\0' for the last element.

Comment: 11 a's as an output

Comment: If you want to input 10 strings, you should use `string a[10]; for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cin >> a[i];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cin >> a;
```

Here you read a string into `a` 10 times. Whatever is entered the first 9 times doesn't matter as they're all written over eachother. If any of them is longer than 10 characters, there's a buffer overflow and you get undefined behavior.

```
string s(a);
```

Here it is constructing an `std::string` using that tenth string that was put into `a`.

```
cout << s;
cout << a[3];
```

Now you're printing that string as well as the fourth character in the array. Since you entered `"a"` 10 times as per your comment, that fourth `char` is uninitialized (the first two are `'a'` and `'\0'` respectively), so this print is undefined behavior.

My guess is that you wanted to read in 10 characters, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

And properly null-terminate the string, like this:

```
a[10] = '\0';
```

Comment: Nitpick:  `a[3]` is actually the 4th character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you, I can't believe I made that mistake. :)